# What (executable) command to calculate charge density using quantum espresso?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, charge-density

I'm trying to calculate the charge density of a structure using quantum espresso, I've already used the DENS.X and DEN.X commands, but in both tests the executable not found error appears. Can someone help me? Or do you know which command I should use?
This is the error message that appears:
mpirun was unable to find the specified executable file, and therefore
did not launch the job.  This error was first reported for process
rank 0; it may have occurred for other processes as well.
NOTE: A common cause for this error is misspelling a mpirun command
line parameter option (remember that mpirun interprets the first
unrecognized command line token as the executable).
Node:       adagp04
Executable: dens.x

and in that link is my .in input file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nyETxvco8x6XL0XqjHwAZnkgVAJ_ws43/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You have previously asked this [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/11892/how-to-calculate-the-charge-density-using-quantum-espresso) and the answer still applies. The command is `pp.x`, not `dens.x`. The input file description for `pp.x` can be found [here](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/INPUT_PP.html)